# Solr: Reloading core from a request handler

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to reload core from my own custom request handler based on a parameter. What are the ways of doing that?

There is a function `SolrCore.reload(SolrCore prev)` function in SolrCore and I am trying to understand what it does. What is the parameter `prev`?
The following code (inside `handleRequestBody`)does not work:

```
String reload_param = params.get(PARAM_RELOAD);
if ((reload_param != null) && reload_param.equals("true")) {
  req.getCore().reload(req.getCore());
  rsp.add("reload", "TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The core itself cannot reload itself.

It is the admin core that reload other cores. This is because internally it creates another instance of the core, and still serve requests from old core, until the new core is ready then it switches to the new core. And this is to get zero-down-time. So, this is done outside the scope of the core itself. It has to be done from a broader scope which is the admin core.

the raw query is like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core1
```

Comment: So, can you tell me the functionality and usage of SolrCore.reload(SolrCore prev)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way core itself can reload itself.

core actually has the coreContainer object which created it. And through coreContainer you can reload the same.

From your code, you can do like this:

```
SolrCore core = req.getCore();
core.getCoreDescriptor().getCoreContainer().reload(core.getName());
```

To be on the safer side, you should run this code in a different thread.